# Why does Steve Rogers wear a different uniform to everyone else in SHIELD?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, captain-america, captain-america-the-winter-soldier

In the Marvel Cinematic Universe, Steve Rogers is shown to be a member of SHIELD (or at least very closely affiliated). Almost every other member of SHIELD wears what appears to be a standard uniform.

Rogers on the other hand does not. Even when just hanging out in briefings in the Avengers he wears his star-spangled outfit. They never really cover his outfit, just that he has superhuman strength and special shield. Even in Winter Soldier he is shown fighting in civilian clothes with his shield.

**So is Steve outfit special, and if not, why doesn't he wear standard SHIELD gear?**

Comment: Public relations. It's a huge PR coup for SHIELD to have someone as famous as Captain America on their team. His iconic uniform is an essential part of his image.

Comment: This is actually a really good question. How is having a famous American hero constantly in costume good for a classified, black ops intelligence organization that doesn't exist as far as the public is concerned? SHIELD didn't have or need PR because it didn't exist.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's because Steve's unique.  He's the only super-human member of S.H.I.E.L.D. (at least in *Captain America: The Winter Soldier*), and he's *Captain freakin' America*.  So, he doesn't wear a stock S.H.I.E.L.D. uniform, he wears one that's evocative of his historical stars and stripes outfit.

It's worth noting that he's not alone in wearing a unique costume.  Both Hawkeye and Black Widow don't wear stock S.H.I.E.L.D. uniforms.  Hawkeye's lacks sleeves.  Black Widow's has the Widow's Sting tazers on her hands and wrists.  So in S.H.I.E.L.D., exceptional agents are granted special uniforms and gear.

Comment: Black Widow also gets to wear skin-tight ass-hugging leather leggings that look like they've been painted on. Er. I've forgotten what point I was going to make. Anyway,  I'll be in my bunk.

Comment: Don't forget, cap is basically a walking piece of national history. So it makes sense that he needs to be distinguished among other agents.